# Postgres CASE statement

Tags: database, postgresql

I cant seem to make the `CASE` part work

```
SELECT ROUND((SUM((to_number(g.grade, '9D99') * s.subjunits)))/(SUM(s.subjunits)), 2),    CASE WHEN g.grade='DRP' THEN '5.00' END
           FROM (grade g
             INNER JOIN registration r ON r.grade_id = g.grade_id)
             INNER JOIN subject s ON s.subjcode = r.subjcode
           WHERE g.grade NOT IN ('INC', 'W', 'INP') 
             AND r.sy = right(to_char(extract(year from now()- interval '1 year'),'9999'), 4)||'-'||right(to_char(extract(year from now()), '9999'),4)
             AND r.sem IN ('1', '2')
             AND r.studid='2012-0004'
           GROUP BY g.grade;
```

all I really want is to do is, if a student has a grade of DRP it'll automatically be counted as 5.0 so that the database could include DRP in calculating the GPA.

but it just says

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: " "
********** Error **********

ERROR: invalid input syntax for type numeric: " "
SQL state: 22P02
```

currently using postgresql 9.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A case statement returns a value that has nothing inherently to do with any of the values that you fed into it. You seem to be thinking that your case statement will update the value of g.grade. It won't. I think what you want to do is use a case statement in place of the value for g.grade in your first function. Maybe:

```
SELECT ROUND((SUM((to_number((case when g.grade='DRP' then '5.00' else g.grade end), '9D99') * s.subjunits)))/(SUM(s.subjunits)), 2)
```

I don't have a copy of Postgres handy so I can't test this, and I'm not familiar with the to_number function (it's been years since I used Postgres). But that's not the point of your question, so if that's not the correct way to call to_number, that's a different issue.

Comment: `to_number()` converts string to numeric. `g.grade` is a `character` so i have to convert it to `numeric`. Oh. I thought the it's the purpose of case. Anyway, I tried your code. It kinda works, it somehow managed to make the DRP grade to 5.0  but I don't get why it's not returning the GPA of the grades but instead listed all the grades of the student.

Comment: Oh wait. It actually calculates the GPA. I removed `GROUP BY` clause. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I could guess what to_number must do, I just meant that I'm not familiar with it so I couldn't swear to the details.

Answer (score 0):

The `CASE` part is ok (although you miss an `ELSE` there, it should still work and optionally return NULL).

The error is caused by the `TO_NUMBER()` function.